# Accessing camera frame pixels in OpenCV Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I have the following c++ code which access the pixels in a IplImage. Here it has a property called 
imageData in the IplImage. I want to convert the following code to OpenCV Android.

```
IplImage *imageIn = cvLoadImage(strFileImage, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
IplImage *imageShirtHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imageShirt), 8, 3);
cvCvtColor(imageShirt, imageShirtHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

int h = imageShirtHSV->height;              
int w = imageShirtHSV->width;           
int rowSize = imageShirtHSV->widthStep; 
char *imOfs = imageShirtHSV->imageData;

for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
        // Get the HSV pixel components
        uchar H = *(uchar*)(imOfs + y*rowSize + x*3 + 0);   // Hue
        uchar S = *(uchar*)(imOfs + y*rowSize + x*3 + 1);   // Saturation
        uchar V = *(uchar*)(imOfs + y*rowSize + x*3 + 2);   // Value (Brightness)
    }
}
```

This is how I converted the above c++ code to OpenCV Android. I used `double[] pixels = imageShirtHSV.get(y, x);` as the equivalent of `char *imOfs = imageShirtHSV->imageData;` in c++. But the following code gives the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I access the HSV values in the double[] pixels array.

```
imageIn = inputFrame.rgba();
Imgproc.cvtColor(imageIn, imageShirtHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

int h = imageShirtHSV.height(); 
int w = imageShirtHSV.width();  
int rowSize = (int)imageShirtHSV.step1();   

for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
        double[] pixels = imageShirtHSV.get(y, x);

        int hVal = (int)pixels[(y*rowSize) + (x) + 0];  // Hue
        int sVal = (int)pixels[(y*rowSize) + (x) + 1];  // Saturation
        int vVal = (int)pixels[(y*rowSize) + (x) + 2];  // Value (Brightness)
    }
}
```

Could somebody please point me how can I convert the c++ `char *imOfs = imageShirtHSV->imageData;` line to OpenCV Android code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

```
double[] pixels = imageShirtHSV.get(y, x);
```

gives you a *single* pixel only. you can't address neighbour values like that.

instead, allocate an array to hold *all* of them, and access that:
(this is also *much* faster!)

```
int h = imageShirtHSV.height(); 
int rowSize = (int)imageShirtHSV.step1();   
byte[] pixels = new byte[h*rowSize];
imageShirtHSV.get(0,0,pixels);

for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
        int hVal = (int)pixels[(y*rowSize) + (x) + 0];  // Hue
        int sVal = (int)pixels[(y*rowSize) + (x) + 1];  // Saturation
        int vVal = (int)pixels[(y*rowSize) + (x) + 2];  // Value (Brightness)
    }
}
```